# React Router 6: Nested routes not working, possibly webpack config

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-router-dom, webpack-5

Nested routes aren't working when trying to build a launcher page of location `/`, and then an init page with a URL style of `setup/init`, and not sure why. React Router v6.

When I go to navigate to the embedded url `/setup/init`, the bundle changes where it's loading from. It goes from `/bundle.js` to `/setup/bundle.js`, which is obviously a `404`.

`index.tsx`: In comments are all the variations attempted

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Launcher />} />
     <Route path="/setup/init" element={<InitContainer />} />
     <Route path="*" element={<h2>Page Not Found</h2>} />
   </Routes>
   {/* <Routes>
     <Route path="/" element={<Launcher />}>
     <Route path="setup/init" element={<InitContainer />} />
     <Route path="*" element={<h2>Page Not Found</h2>} />
   </Routes> */}
   {/* <Routes>
     <Route path="/" element={<Launcher />}>
       <Route path="setup">
         <Route index element={<InitContainer />} />
         <Route path="init" element={<InitContainer />} />
       </Route>
     </Route>
     <Route path="*" element={<h2>Page Not Found</h2>} />
   </Routes> */}
</BrowserRouter>
```

`webpack.config.js`: Tried multiple webpack configs as well based on other stack answers

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/client/index.tsx',
  output: {
    // publicPath: '/' <--- This lead to all containers being the launcher container
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
    chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].[contenthash].js.map'
  },
  ...
  devServer: {
    port: 3001,
    open: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
  ...
}
```

I also attempted adding the [Outlet](https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/api#outlet) to the `Launcher` or `InitContainer`, and it didn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your webpack config:

```
output: {
    [your existing config] ,
    publicPath: "/",
},
```

Comment: I did try this, and it didn't work, though this is the solution from the docs.